# Python RandomForest classifier (how to test it)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have been able to create a RandomForestClassifier on a dataset.

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state = 101)
```

I can then use it on the test data like this:

```
prediction = pd.DataFrame(clf.predict(x)) # x = Matrix of predictor values
```

So my question is, how can I test clf.predict outside of Python, how can I see the values that is using and how can I test it "manually" for example if you get the betas in a Regression you can then use those values in Excel and replicate the model. How to do this with RandomForests in Python?

Also is there a similar metric to Rsquared to test the model's explication power?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `RandomForestClassifier` is an ensemble of trees which means it is composed by multiple trees.

To be able to test the trees I would suggest to do it in Python itself, you can access all the trees in the `estimators_` attribute of the classifier and subsequently export them as graphs with `export_graphviz` from `sklearn.tree` module.

If you insist on exporting the trees you will need to export all the rules that each tree is composed by. For that, you can follow [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py) instructions from the sklearn docs.

Regarding the metrics, for a classification problem you could use `accuracy_score` from `sklearn.metrics` module.